# cannot dismissViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the `CustomNavigationViewController` where I check whether or not user registered already. if yes, then it directly open `UserProfileVewController`, skips registration or login screen.

Whenever user clicks on the logout button, then I am trying to dismiss `UserProfileVewController`, but nothing happens.

**CustomNavigationViewController.m**

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    if([self isRegistered])
    {
        UserProfileViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserProfileVewController"];
        [self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**UserProfileVewController.m**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "push" a ViewController, you want to "pop" back to the VC that pushed it.

When you "present" a ViewController, that's when you want to "dismiss" it.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

View controller navigation operates in two pattern.
1. Presentation (Modal views)
2. Parentage (Containment)

1. Presentation: To move from first controller to second we use

   [self presentViewController:secondController animated:YES completion:nil]

   Now, to come back to first controller, In second controller it should be

   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewController animated:YES]
2. Parentage: NavigationController, TabBarController are the examples.  NavigationController acts as stack of controllers where as TabBarController array of controllers.

   Since you are using navigation controller and pushing the controller into navigation controller, to com back it needs to pop rather than dismiss. So, in second view (child view controller) it should be written as

   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

If you push the viewcontroller ,you cannot dismiss that viewcontroller just go back to the controller only

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if present the viewcontroller ,you want to back the controller

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];